# Bizarre zooming issue in Chrome

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css

I have a very irritating issue on the live site I'm designing for a client. I've dug into the CSS and HTML of the site to no avail. This *only* occurs in Chrome. The work in progress can be found at live.dancingsheepcoffee.com

Background:

- Using Wordpress as CMS, theme designed with Underscores (_s)
- Also using 960.gs system to aid layout design
- Issue only occurs in Chrome; IE, Firefox, Safari, all display great.

Here's the breakdown:

- On a virgin load of the site, the page displays as designed, issue free.
- Upon a refresh (or second visit) the page loads "zoomed in" almost 200%, for no apparent reason. Text, navigation, headers, sidebar, and even the tiled background image. Site-wide. The main logo seems to be unaffected.
- Zooming out and then back in (i.e., zoom to 90% then back to 100%) 'fixes' the page and displays as designed.
- Also following the link to the same page from the menu bar loads the page correctly, however the content "jumps" sizes before displaying the correct content.
- Content box remains at 960px wide (except when user toggles zoom, appropriately)
- Background image also "zooms" on page load but then displays correctly when resolved above.

And the worst part is, I can't duplicate this on my main work computer, but the issue displays on every other computer. The way the issue works, it sounds like it's something on the client side, as the web server seems to render the page perfect every time, but perhaps the cached version isn't working. A thought to consider.

I greatly appreciate the time considered and help with this issue. I'll provide any applicable code to aide troubleshooting. Thanks again!

Comment: It is advised against linking to unknown sites (could have malware or something on it). If you could create a codepen or JSfiddle to replicate the issue, more people would be inclined to take a look.

Comment: I definitely understand the concern there, rest assured this is not the case. However, I don't believe I'll be able to duplicate the entire site, issue intact, especially since it's managed in Wordpress.  Is there another way to display the site while keeping my fellow community members free from risk?

Comment: I'm not asking for you to replicate wordpress. None of us want to debug an entire wordpress install. If you want help, you are going to need to distill the issue into a small enough chunk that it is easy to replicate.